# Connect to Metro server to develop JavaScript

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm having a constant issue with Xcode and Metro server on my new MacBook Air with M1 - I'm unable to connect to Metro server from iPhone 14 Pro when I run `npm start` and then build an iOS application in Xcode.

What's frustrating is that from time to time it's suddenly possible to connect to Metro server from iPhone, usually in situations when I don't use iPhone/MacBook for a longer time, change local network, change Apple ID (today) and even once when I managed to pair Xcode with iPhone wirelessly (yesterday - since then I couldn't accomplish the same).

MacBook and iPhone are on the same WiFi.
I tried restarting both devices.
I tried deleting Pods and modules and reinstall them.
I tried deleting cache: `npm start --reset-cache`.
I tried to `Configure Bundler` on iPhone.
I tried reinstalling Xcode.
I tried reinstalling node and react-native.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.